# Django: Are row level permissions for instance specific rules, or are they about views?

Tags: django, django-models, multi-tenant, django-authentication

Sorry for the confusing title. I tried to make it less verbose, but...

What I'm wondering is: Does Django's new [row level permissions](http://packages.python.org/django-authority/) (a) fix the design problem that comes with multi-tenant applications (I don't mean multiple users, but rather multiple instances working with the same db/db schema), or is it (b) just a more complex version of permissions that allows you to manage permissions at the row level based on the standard User and Auth apps' rules.

(ie, I want to limit access to objects a, b, c to this account, and d, e, f to this account VS a user can access the title of a blog post but not the content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django-authority let's you implement row-level permissions along with django's table-level permissions using the same syntax for both. So it allows you to restrict users A, B to operate only on object C, but not D.

Restricting access to the field-level (title, content) is even more granular and cannot be handled here.